# проблемы с плагином Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Добрый день! Установила плагин вордпрес(3.5) slideshow-gallery, со стороны админки все работает, а вот сам плагин на странице не отображается, http://31-web.ru/
в чем может быть проблема? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у плагина были проблемы с внутренним подключением js, нужно было дополнительно путь прописать